# Multiple ear instances

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ant, ejb, geronimo

Currently I am developing an application composed of basically three modules: 1 ejb and two web apps. Using ant I am exporting this as a single ear.

My client asked to run multiple instances of the same ear on the same server. I was able to change application names and context path so they do not clash, however there is a problem with EJBs. Apache Geronimo can't startup EBJs with the same name event if they live on different ear/jar, etç.

Is there any way to make the EJB deployment specific for each "installation", or isn't possible and therefore I need to strip EJBs Jar from the web apps enclosed on the EAR ?

I would appreciate any help/hint.

Regards,
Ivan Frias

Comment: The idea of having EJBs on a different jar should be that those work across multiple applications, why would you need to have same EJBs deployed many times?

Comment: Yes, you are right, doesn't make any sense to have several copies of the same EJB across different ears. I've changed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it will be enough to have the many copies of web applications with one EJB.

Then you can separate EJB module and web modules and then load one EJB and N copies of web applications in the application server.

But it may cause some errors because of one EJB for many web applications.
Otherwise you have to run three instances of the application server because you will not be able to use equal EJB even separated by different jars/packages.

Comment: Yes, this was in fact the solution I opted not only because it gives the needed flexibility in therms of deployment but also because it respects the original requirement.